# What is Unicode and ANSI names

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

What is Unicode and ANSI names in the attached screenshot.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m42ab.png)
It is mentioned at the end of the page in this link [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Old windows (pre-NT) used ANSI codepages (1 byte per character, different in every region of the world). From NT onward Unicode was introduced. Pre-NT all the API where ANSI (so for example `LoadLibraryA(LPCSTR)` accepted an ANSI name for the name of the library. From NT onward a new version of all the API where introduced, using Unicode (`LoadLibraryW(LPCWSTR)`). So in Windows >= NT there are **two** API for loading libraries, ANSI and Unicode.

Then there is a third version, `LoadLibrary`, that is only a `#define`. The value of this #define (that can be `LoadLibraryA` or `LoadLibraryW`, depends if the `#define UNICODE` is set or not) (the same for `ShellExecute` that can be `ShellExecuteA` or `ShellExecuteW`). So in your source code you can use directly the `LoadLibraryA`, the `LoadLibraryW` and a third version, `LoadLibrary`, that depending on a preprocessor macro will use one of the other two. If you want to use the "agnostic" `LoadLibrary` versions of the API you should use `TCHAR`, `LPTSTR`, `LPCTSTR`, `_T("foo")` that, through the preprocessor, will be changed to `char`, `char*`, `const char*`, `"foo"` or to `wchar_t`, `wchar_t*`, `const wchar_t*`, `L"foo"`.

But note that in 2017 (and in general from when Windows ME was dead) it is **wrong** to use ANSI api. You should always target UNICODE (or target the agnostic version and `#define UNICODE`)

Comment: The main reason why using ANSI API is wrong is because ANSI is not a real codepage, but whatever 8-bit encoding happens to be used in the localized version of Windows. So if you write a nice ANSI program using Greek Windows (and greek letters) it will *silently* garble all your Greek texts in non-greek versions of Windows!

Comment: @rodrigo I consider much more important the fact that with ANSI methods you can't even see the whole file-system in a correct way.